# I want to create an Activity in android in which a image appears randomly on screen for short time

Tags: android

I also want to capture if the user clicked on that image while it was on display.

Comment: a single image is to appear at random places on screen.

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and which particular bits you're having difficulty with. We're not just going to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest way that comes right out of the top of my mind would be to have a set of imageviews on display with the same image and only enabling one image view at a time. and setting an onclick listener to it.
or also you can have one image view and change its position dynamically. and set it an onlicklistener.

Comment: can you please tell me how to dynamically change the position of image view?

Comment: here `ImageView image;
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(100,0, 0,0);

// OR
params.topMargin= 100;
image.setLayoutParams(params);`

you need to write a code to generate different parameters to place the image in different location, which is very easy to do. i hope this helped.

Comment: thanx anurag...your ideas gave me a new line of thought...would try them tonight :)

Comment: you're welcome. but do take care that you frame your questions properly to get a better response from the members. its really important to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single `ImageView` placed inside of a simple layout like `FrameLayout` to display on the activity.  You can manage hide/show by calling `setVisibility()` on the view.

You can move the view around inside that layout frame using the `offsetTopAndBottom()` and `offsetLeftAndRight()` methods, passing in a randomized value to shift the view around the screen.  Keep in mind this is an offset, not an absolute position set, so you have to make sure you don't send the image off-screen.

You can manage the user taps by attaching an `OnClickListener` to the `ImageView`, which will only get called if the user taps the image while it is visible.

HTH

Comment: thank you for the response,i would try to implement it